# Node.js - Handlebars Referencing Variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, key, handlebars.js

In a handlebars view - is there a way to reference an objects key that has a space in it?  The key is "Record Number" in the object, but I can't seem to be able to reference it in the view.  For instance - I have the following code in the view:

```
{{#each records}}
        {{this.'Record ID'}}            
{{/each}}
```

The array "records" from the controller:

```
records = [
    {
        'Record ID':3
    },
    {
        'Record ID':3
    }
];
```

The error I am getting:

```
 Expecting 'ID', got 'STRING'
```

I have also tried "this['Record Number']" with the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use brackets in conjunction with dots, without quotes:

```
{{#each records}}
  {{this.[Record ID]}}
{{/each}}
```